# When to use Volley for network operations?

Tags: android, android-volley

I am developing an Android application which has 3 main types of network operations :-

1) OAuth type login authentication which is a 2 step process - first one is getting the access token and second is getting user details.

2) Post operations when user clicks a button only working with text data (no images)

3) Background sync operations where multiple databases will be updated on the client and server and most of these tables are not related to one other. So they can be performed in parallel.

So for these network operations should I use Volley or custom async http implementations?

What if I have images to upload and download in these operations.

Answer (score 0):

Volley is much better that custom async operations and handles much more cases. The question would be more which http client library to use. There quite a few out there but Volley does a good job.

for point 1) you need to apply you custom flow and requests here but it is not difficult as Volley is quite modular

for uploading and downloading images you will also have to do some more work because it does not come out-of-the-box.

I would also suggest to try [jus](https://github.com/apptik/jus). it is based on volley but including many handy features, which will help you in your particular case as well.